# Fatal error: Non-abstract method News_model::__construct() must contain body [CodeIgniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying the tutorial in CodeIgniter User Guide Version 2.2.0. i just followed 
the code pasted but i got this error message. what is really wrong here?

```
Fatal error: Non-abstract method News_model::__construct() must contain 
body in /var/www/leomel/application/models/news_model.php on line 3
```

the source code:

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {
   public function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('news_model');
   }

   public function index()
   {
     $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
     $data['title'] = 'News archive';

     $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
     $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
     $this->load->view('templates/footer');
   }

   public function view($slug)
   {
     $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
     if (empty($data['news_item']))
     {
        show_404();
     }

     $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

     $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
     $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
     $this->load->view('templates/footer');
   }
}
```

Comment: can you show your news model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error belongs to a different class `News_model` whereas you've shown the code from `News`

And the error is self descriptive - you must specify a method body unless it's abstract.

What you presumably have:

```
public function __construct();
```

what you must have:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // method's body
}
```

Comment: i accidentally put a semicolon after the function inside the News_model class. solved thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Easy, add {} to your constructor in your News_model class.

```
__construct(){/*body*/}
```